# Control of running Thread using multiple threading concept of java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I just want to start and stop the thread when return key is pressed.
Here thread is stopped fine but i cant Start that thread again please help.
Also explain me the use of volatile keyword .Is it helpful for me to over come this problem.

```
public class Sync extends Thread{

    public boolean meth= true;
    public void run(){
        while(meth){
            System.out.println("hello");
            try {

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
           }
    }
    public void shutdown(){
       meth=false;
    }
    public void startup(){
        meth=true;
    }



}
```

**MAIN CLASS``**

```
    package com.Sync;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class SyncMain {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws InterruptedException{
        Sync hi= new Sync();
        hi.start();
        System.out.println("press enter to stop");

        Scanner d= new Scanner(System.in);

        d.nextLine();
        hi.shutdown();
        System.out.println("press enter to start");
        d.nextLine();
        hi.startup();



    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   run:
press enter to stop
hello
hello
hello
hello

press enter to start

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java/28235062#28235062) to know more about volatile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread's are not re-entrant, that is, once they exit the `run` method, they can't be restarted, you need to create a new instance.

One solution would be to create a new instance of `Sync` and start it, but a  better solution, based on you code might, be to use a `wait` lock to "pause" the thread and the allow it to resume, for example...

```
public static class Sync implements Runnable {

    private AtomicBoolean keepRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private AtomicBoolean pause = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private ReentrantLock lckPause = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition conPause = lckPause.newCondition();

    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning.get() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            while (pause.get() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                lckPause.lock();
                try {
                    System.out.println("Paused");
                    conPause.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    lckPause.unlock();
                }
            }
            if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("hello");
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
        if (pause.get() != paused) {
            pause.set(paused);
            if (!paused) {
                lckPause.lock();
                try {
                    conPause.signal();
                } finally {
                    lckPause.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void terminate() {
        keepRunning.set(false);
        setPaused(false);
    }

}
```

This basically sets up two loops, one to keep the thread running until it's "terminated" and one to trap the "pause" condition...

Then you could do something like...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sync hi = new Sync();
    Thread t = new Thread(hi);
    t.start();

    Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("press enter to pause");
    d.nextLine();
    hi.setPaused(true);
    System.out.println("press enter to resume");
    d.nextLine();
    hi.setPaused(false);
    System.out.println("press enter to terminate");
    d.nextLine();
    hi.terminate();

    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Has terminated");
}
```

to simply run it...

You should note that it's generally discouraged to extend directly from `Thread`  and it is generally encouraged to use a separate `Runnable`, there are many reasons, but one which you will find most useful in future is `Runnable` is more widely supported in different parts of the API (like the `Executors` API) making it a much more flexible option

Have a look at the [Concurrency Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more details, in particular [Lock Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)